# How to initialize a list struct in C?

Tags: c, struct, initialization

Ive been given this list data structure cannot figure out how to create an instance of it.
I want to create a list struct as a global object. Because the constructor data type is a list pointer, I used`List* list1 = List_create();` but gcc gives an error saying that initializer element is not constant.
If I omit the * and write `List list1 = List_create();` it says variable list1 has initializer but incomplete type. I don't really know what is going wrong. Usually when I work with structs, I initialize its data members individually and am not familiar with using constructors.
How do I create an instance of this list structure?

//this is the struct

```
    


typedef struct List_s List;
struct List_s {
    Node* pFirstNode;
    Node* pLastNode;
    Node* pCurrentNode;
    int count;
    List* pNextFreeHead;
    enum ListOutOfBounds lastOutOfBoundsReason;
};

//this is the constructor
List* List_create()
{
    if (!s_isInitialized) {
        initializeDataStructures();
    }

    mutexLock();

    // Get next free head
    List* pList = s_pFirstFreeHead;
    if (pList) {
        s_pFirstFreeHead = s_pFirstFreeHead->pNextFreeHead;
        pList->pNextFreeHead = NULL;
    }

    mutexUnlock();
    return pList;
}


//This is the function that is called inside List_create
static void initializeDataStructures() {
    mutexInitialize();
    
    mutexLock();

    assert(LIST_MAX_NUM_NODES > 0);
    assert(LIST_MAX_NUM_HEADS > 0);


    // Nodes
    s_pFirstFreeNode = &s_nodes[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < LIST_MAX_NUM_NODES; i++) {
        s_nodes[i].pItem = NULL;
        s_nodes[i].pPrev = NULL;
        s_nodes[i].pNext = NULL;
        if (i + 1 < LIST_MAX_NUM_NODES) {
            s_nodes[i].pNext = &s_nodes[i+1];
        }
    }

    // Heads
    s_pFirstFreeHead = &s_heads[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < LIST_MAX_NUM_HEADS; i++) {
        s_heads[i].count = 0;
        s_heads[i].pCurrentNode = NULL;
        s_heads[i].lastOutOfBoundsReason = LIST_OOB_START;
        s_heads[i].pFirstNode = NULL;
        s_heads[i].pLastNode = NULL;
        s_heads[i].pNextFreeHead = NULL;
        if (i + 1 < LIST_MAX_NUM_HEADS) {
            s_heads[i].pNextFreeHead = &s_heads[i + 1];
        }
    }
    s_isInitialized = true;
    mutexUnlock();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where is that `main` function where you get an error? Also where is your `createListe` or `Create_list` function you mention? Please show the code that causes your trouble, not something totally different. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and as a new visitor, also read [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: ... or the `List_create()` posted.

Comment: My bad, I rush to post the question and got the wording wrong but I've fixed the question. I basically just want to know how would I create a struct when the constructor is given like that.

Comment: Now your issue is very different. You can use the result of a function call to initialize a local variable in `main` as you claimed in first version of the question. But you cannot call functions to initialize global variables. They are initialized before any function can be called. Besides that, why do you still not show the code that causes the error?

Comment: You just need to initialize it from within a function, such as `main`.  The point is that you're using a function call to initialize it, which is executable code, so of course it can't be used in a static initializer.

Comment: Thank you Gerhardh and Tom. I placed it in the main and its working. I did not post the main because I had just rough coded it and almost every line had an error. The List_create lines were the first ones and were standalone. But its resolved now so thanks again!